# modal window not visible

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

friends i am using given below code for modal window 
but i only get black screen in output and none of the modal window component
following error is encountered

> onExtensionMsgReceived:ddBgIsReady DragAndDropController.js:173
>   onExtensionMsgReceived:getSettings DragAndDropController.js:173
>   onExtensionMsgReceived:getSearchSources DragAndDropController.js:173
>   onExtensionMsgReceived:getShareSources

please help me

```
<head>
 <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
       });
   });

</script>
<title>Dash Board</title>
</head> 
 <body>
<p><a href="#" id="btn-show-modal">Show Modal Dialog</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="dialog-example">

    <div class = "modal-header">
    <h1>My ModalDialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>

    <div class ="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">close</a>
    <a href ="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modal markup is not correct for Bootstrap v3.
Consult the examples: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

In particular, you shouldn't use `hide`, and you're missing `modal-dialog` and `modal-content` `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

add bootstrap.css,jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="#" id="btn-show-modal">Show Modal Dialog</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="dialog-example">

    <div class = "modal-header">
    <h1>My ModalDialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>

    <div class ="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" id='btn-close'>close</a>
    <a href ="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $("#btn-show-modal").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-example").modal('show');
       });

    $("#btn-close").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-example").modal('hide');

    });
   });

</script> 
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Tw4a/